# No application in unity dash after upgrade packages in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I regularly upgrade system. Last night i upgraded some packages (ubuntu-base). Now there is not application in unity dash (in application lens). Other lens (file, music etc) are just working fine. Only problem is that i can't see any application in application lens.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg-recomfigure -A`?

Comment: @Dillmo WOW. It's works. But as far as i remember, software updater didn't show any error. Even when i was installing software using apt-get i didn't get any error, strange. Please post your comment as answer so that i can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can probably just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -A`. Your problem is likely that your Dash configuration wasn't updated properly, so it cannot see any apps. Running the command will reconfigure Ubuntu, so any problems with your configuration files will be flushed out there.

Comment: My dpkg-reconfigure doesn't have the -A option anymore.

Comment: Replacing -A with -a made it run, but everything was not found (so it did nothing). Ideas?

Comment: This did not work for me either in 16.10, but PocketSam's suggestion below did.

Answer (score 1):

Seemes like you have to remove `~/.cache/software-center/*`, log out and log in again. It seems to have helped me.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.10.  Thanks!